# How to Create a Column of Ranks While Grouping in R

Tags: r

I am using R and I want to create a column showing a sequence or rank, while grouping by two factors (hhid and period).

For example, I have this data set:

```
hhid perid
1000 1     
1000 1
1000 1
1000 2
1000 2
2000 1
2000 1
2000 1
2000 1
2000 2
2000 2
```

I want to add a column called "actno" like this:

```
hhid perid actno
1000 1     1
1000 1     2
1000 1     3
1000 2     1
1000 2     2
2000 1     1
2000 1     2
2000 1     3
2000 1     4
2000 2     1
2000 2     2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for plyr. Just use `ave` and `seq`:

```
> dat$actno <- with( dat, ave(hhid, hhid, perid, FUN=seq))
> dat
   hhid perid actno
1  1000     1     1
2  1000     1     2
3  1000     1     3
4  1000     2     1
5  1000     2     2
6  2000     1     1
7  2000     1     2
8  2000     1     3
9  2000     1     4
10 2000     2     1
11 2000     2     2
```

The first argument in this instance could be either column or you could do it with the slightly less elegant bu perhaps more clear:

```
dat$actno <- with( dat, ave(hhid, hhid, perid, FUN=function(x) seq(length(x) ) ) )
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have lots of groups or large data, `data.table` is the way to go for efficiency of time and memory

```
# assuming your data is in a data.frame called DF
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(DF)


DT[, ActNo := seq_len(.N), by = list(hhid,perid)]
```

note that `.N` gives the number of rows in the subset by grouping (see `?data.table` for more details)

Comment: Is there a quick way to deal with ties in data.table?

Answer (score 2):

if your data is called `urdat` then without `plyr` you can do:

```
df <- urdat[order(urdat$hhid, urdat$perid),]
df$actno <- sequence(rle(df$perid)$lengths)
```

Answer (score 1):

the `plyr` package can do this nicely:

```
library(plyr)
dat <- structure(list(hhid = c(1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 2000L, 
2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L), perid = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L)), .Names = c("hhid", "perid"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))

ddply(dat, .(hhid, perid), transform, actno=seq_along(perid))

   hhid perid actno
1  1000     1     1
2  1000     1     2
3  1000     1     3
4  1000     2     1
5  1000     2     2
6  2000     1     1
7  2000     1     2
8  2000     1     3
9  2000     1     4
10 2000     2     1
11 2000     2     2
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Justin... It works with my data set, but because of a huge number of groups, it took long time and my computer significantly slowed down after running your code. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @user1663986 `plyr` is a nice way to explore data so long as it is small.  Either of the other answers, particularly DWin's will be very fast and work well on large data.

Comment: @user1663986 And how did you get on with mnel's answer?

Answer (score -4):

Pseudocode:

```
For each unique value of `hhid` `h`
    For each unique value of `perid` `p`
        counter = 0;
        For each row of table where `hhid==h && perid==p`
            counter++;
            Assign counter to `actno` of this column
```

Should be trivial to implement, especially with a [data frame](http://msenux.redwoods.edu/math/R/dataframe.php).