# how to create a column including the maximum value of another column in R?

Tags: r, data.table, plyr

Using R, I would like to create a new column (MaxAct) showing the maximum numbers of a different column (ActNo) while grouping by two factors (HHID and PERID)

For example, I have this data set:

```
UID HHID PERID ActNo
1   1000 1     1
2   1000 1     2
3   1000 1     3
4   1000 2     1
5   1000 2     2
6   2000 1     1
7   2000 1     2
8   2000 1     3
9   2000 1     4
10  2000 2     1
11  2000 2     2
```

Then I want to add the new column (MaxAct) as follows:

```
UID HHID PERID ActNo MaxAct
1   1000 1     1     3
2   1000 1     2     3
3   1000 1     3     3
4   1000 2     1     2
5   1000 2     2     2
6   2000 1     1     4
7   2000 1     2     4
8   2000 1     3     4
9   2000 1     4     4
10  2000 2     1     2
11  2000 2     2     2
```

Comment: It's much easier for us to help you if you post a working example along with your question. Also, the command `dput()` would properly help you in making your working example.

Comment: If this remains unsolved, your really _do_ need to use dput() to provide an illustration that has all of the aspects of your problem. Just posting what might be a console output often fails to represent  the internal structure of you data object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
dat$MaxAct <- with(dat, ave(ActNo, HHID, PERID, FUN=max) )
```

For problems involving single vectors and grouping where you want the length of the result to equal the row count, `ave` is your function of choice. For more complicated problems, the `lapply(split(dat, fac), FUN)` approach may be needed or use `do.call(rbind, by( ...))`

If you have missing values:

```
dat$MaxAct <- with(dat, ave(ActNo, HHID, PERID, FUN=function(x) max(x, na.rm=TRUE) )  )
```

Comment: Thank you very much, DWin... But I have an error message like "no non-missing arguments to max" Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: It works for me, but if your data has missing values (which your illustration did not suggest), then adding na.rm=TRUE as a further argument to `max` would be needed.

Comment: @DWin, the error "no non-missing arguments to max" is not thrown because of the presence of NA values. But because he is applying max to a NULL or 0 length argument: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/error-message-re-max-i-but-code-and-output-seen-O-K-td891889.html

Answer (score 6):

This is standard fare for `plyr` with `mutate` or `transform`, base R `ave`  or `data.table` (which might be considered a sledgehammer for a peanuts here).

The `plyr` and `ave`  approaches has been addressed so

## data.table

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(DF)
DT[,MaxAct := max(ActNo), by = list(HHID, PERID)]
```

Given the size of the data the memory efficient and fast nature of  `data.table` is perhaps not required.

having read your previous question [How to Create a Column of Ranks While Grouping in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12377447), so we know that `max(ActNo)` is simply the number of rows in each group then

```
DT[,MaxAct := .N, by = list(HHID, PERID)]
```

will work, and be marginally quicker.

Comment: The ave approach was first, but it's so quick and elegant that you probably missed it.

Comment: Yarp, I've edited my response. Ave is elegant, I am starting to think data.table is elegant. Perhaps I should get out more.

Answer (score 4):

There are several approaches in R to do achieve this task. For me, the easiest way to do this is to use the `plyr` package

```
require(plyr)
ddply(dat, .(HHID, PERID), transform, MaxAct = max(ActNo))

   UID HHID PERID ActNo MaxAct
1    1 1000     1     1      3
2    2 1000     1     2      3
3    3 1000     1     3      3
4    4 1000     2     1      2
5    5 1000     2     2      2
6    6 2000     1     1      4
7    7 2000     1     2      4
8    8 2000     1     3      4
9    9 2000     1     4      4
10  10 2000     2     1      2
11  11 2000     2     2      2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- read.table(textConnection("UID HHID PERID ActNo
1   1000 1     1
2   1000 1     2
3   1000 1     3
4   1000 2     1
5   1000 2     2
6   2000 1     1
7   2000 1     2
8   2000 1     3
9   2000 1     4
10  2000 2     1
11  2000 2     2"), header=T)


> ddply(df, .(HHID, PERID), transform, MaxAct = length(unique(ActNo)) )
   UID HHID PERID ActNo MaxAct
1    1 1000     1     1      3
2    2 1000     1     2      3
3    3 1000     1     3      3
4    4 1000     2     1      2
5    5 1000     2     2      2
6    6 2000     1     1      4
7    7 2000     1     2      4
8    8 2000     1     3      4
9    9 2000     1     4      4
10  10 2000     2     1      2
11  11 2000     2     2      2
```

Comment: Your question says max but your example answer shows length of unique so i went with that.